# MySQL 5.7 enforce SSL

Tags: mysql, encryption, ssl, certificate

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and I want to set up SSL to force the client to use a cert.
This cert is a self-signed cert that I generate.
I have the cert for both server and client being:
- CA
- cert
- key

Where the CA has the cert for server and client.
I then configured the config file (mysqld.conf) to use the cert:

```
[mysqld]
ssl
ssl-ca=/database/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/database/mysql/ssl/master-public.pem
ssl-key=/database/mysql/ssl/master-private.pem
```

And run the command to enforce it:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `database` TO 'user'@'192.168.10.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL;
```

I can see SSL is enabled and it's picking up the right files running the command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl%';
```

However, from the client machine (192.168.10.10. in this example) I can connect via command line without specifying any cert and it just connects.
I can see the connection is using SSL with:

```
mysql> \s
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
```

But the idea is to allow t he connection only if I use the certs.
Is there a way to enforce it to make sure it won't connect without specifying the cert ?
So I can configure the application to use it and make sure other applications wouldn't access it.

Comment: For this, it looks like you may need to use the [`require_secure_transport` server system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_require_secure_transport), which is "off" by default.

Answer (score 0):

That would [REQUIRE ISSUER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) in your user definition.